# Can I install an additional oracle database on one node of an oracle cluster (RAC)?

Tags: oracle, clustering, installation

Let's say I have a two-node Oracle RAC environment. Can I install an additional Oracle database on one of the node?

Thanks.

Comment: Just be *very* careful if this is a production environment... (note: best not to mix production/test databases on the same servers...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install another database on the same server that is already running one instance of a RAC database, yes.